# Question about Importing Swift code into objective c code

Tags: ios, swift

I read this documentation for importing swift code into objective c.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_swift_into_objective-c

I have a few questions.

1. Can I put @objc annotation for a Struct?
2. 

Do I need to inherit all the class that I want to export to obj to be child of NSobject ? I am getting error 'error: only classes that inherit from NSObject can be declared @objc'

3. When I export a swift class with @objc, I need to add @objc to all its parent classes, protocol and interface and also class and structure in all its methods, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Objective-C cannot see a native Swift struct.
2. Yes. Objective-C classes must basically be derived from NSObject. Objective-C can be made aware of the existence of other classes, but it cannot do anything useful with them.
3. You can mark the class with `@objcMembers`, in which case you will give everything within it full visibility to Objective-C.